# Why I can't utilize my 2nd 1TB Hard drive in VESTACP?

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos

I have an server with the following specifications

> Intel Core i3-530 2.93 GHz
>
> 4GB RAM Storage
>
> 2x 1000GB HW RAID
>
> CentOS 7.2, 64 bits

with NO RAID

I installed VESTA CP. It works OK but I have a little problem. I'm only able to utilize 1 hard drive and not second (when I upload data more than 1 TB, my first hard drive is full so it means that the 2nd drive is not useful)

[b]lsblk commend [/b]

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─sda1   8:1    0   200M  0 part /boot
├─sda2   8:2    0 930.3G  0 part /
└─sda3   8:3    0     1G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   0 931.5G  0 disk
```

I am newbie and I need help. Any clue that allows me to utilize my second hard drive.I heard about LVM but it makes me confuse about.
If I did LVM it will format my data on drives.

Comment: You need to mount the second disk in a directory somewhere, and put the files you want on that disk in that directory.

Comment: but what happens when my 1st drive full by VestaCP? With sFTP i can able to  put files on 2nd drive manual but it will not work with VestaCP